# how to format date and time?

Tags: xml, datetime

I understand my question is pretty incomplete .. I am basically writting date and time to xml to record when the file was created .. The exact format i want is "04/04/12 13:30:40"

I tried to different ways to get what I want and the closest i found is using this ..

```
           Dim Date_Time As Date = Date.Now
```

which will show like

[image]

Pretty close rite ? but when I write it variable Date_Time to XML it becomes totally different .. such as ..

```
         2012-05-02T09:24:48.7005197+01:00
```

Hope someone can help me out .. THanks ..

PS. I was using

```
          Dim xmlDoc As New XDocument(
          New XElement("FILE",
          New XAttribute("FileDate", Date_Time))
```

to create xml.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try something like this when you write to the file:

```
date_time.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
```

I think adding **tt** to the end will give you the AM/PM bit if you want that too.

Just to add a bit more info, the following link gives you a example of all the different date formats ... good for reference... [Click me](http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View00FF7904-B510-468C-A2C8-F859AA20581F.htm)

Comment: Thanks Paul .. I never knew that I can format the date like that .. I also needed to change Dim Date_Time As String instead of Date otherwise it was still using a different format.

Comment: Very helpful link as well .. :D

Answer (score 1):

Date format are interpreted different depending on the country someone is coming from. The date 04/05/12 means for example:

- 4th of May, 2012 (if you are coming from UK)
- 5th of April, 2012 (if you are coming from USA)
- 12th of May, 2004 (someone else)

The purpose of XML is to have an extensible exchange format for data. To be sure someone else understands the meaning of a given date, following date format ([described in ISO 8601](http://www.iso.org/iso/iso_catalogue/catalogue_ics/catalogue_detail_ics.htm?csnumber=40874)) will be used:

- date format: YYYY-MM-DD
- date and time format: YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss

It's a common practice to use the ISO date format in XML. You don't have to follow this practice but it might be a good idea.

Additional advantage of this date format:

- easily comparable and sortable
- larger units are written in front of smaller units

According to my experiences it's very helpful to use this representation. It's even possible to make simple tests via XPath and compare different dates (greater or smaller or between).

Comment: Agreed. There are exceptions, but generally in XML it's best to use the canonical (standard, international) date format, and then localize it for a particular audience at presentation time.

Comment: I like the part that I can use XPath to search for specific time ranges. It's a lot more complicated if you are using a different notation.